# Object only spawning server side [NetworkServer/NetworkClient]

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I'm trying to get started with Unity's networking features and have encountered an issue whilst trying to spawn objects. I've tried to create a simple demo following the documentation found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSpawning.html), the server spawns an object which changes colour every second, each connected client should see this object and its colour changes. The client/server are connecting but the object is only appearing on the server end (no error messages).

***Client.cs***

```
public class Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject boxPrefab;

    private NetworkClient networkClient;

    private static void OnConnected(NetworkMessage networkMessage)
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("[ID: {0}] Connected.", networkMessage.conn.connectionId));
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        networkClient = new NetworkClient();

        ClientScene.RegisterPrefab(boxPrefab);  
        networkClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);
        networkClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 5172);

        Debug.Log("Connecting...");
    }
}
```

***Server.cs***

```
public class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BoxSpawner boxSpawner;

    private void OnConnection(NetworkMessage networkMessage)
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("[ID: {0}] Connected.", networkMessage.conn.connectionId));
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnection);
        NetworkServer.Listen("127.0.0.1", 5172);
        Debug.Log("Listening...");

        NetworkServer.SpawnObjects();
        boxSpawner.Spawn();
    }
}
```

***BoxSpawner.cs***

```
public class BoxSpawner : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public GameObject boxPrefab;

    public void Spawn()
    {
        GameObject box = (GameObject) Instantiate(boxPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        NetworkServer.Spawn(box);
    }
}
```

Both the client and server have a prefab named Box which has the following script on it, along with a NetworkIdentity component.

***Box.cs***

```
public class Box : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SyncVar]
    private Color32 color;

    private IEnumerator ChangeColour()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            color = new Color32((byte)Random.Range(0, 255), (byte)Random.Range(0, 255),
                (byte)Random.Range(0, 255), 255);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        if (isServer)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ChangeColour());
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = color;
    }
}
```

I've also uploaded both the client/server projects to a GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/b-reynolds/UnityNetworking), if someone could take a look and give me a hand I'd really appreciate it, thank you.

Note: I'm trying to accomplish this without using the NetworkManager.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your code very quickly I can see one thing, which i do not know if it is the reason, but you register your boxPrefab on the client. that should be done on the server I would guess.